# Nuxt BaseUrl from domaine name

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, middleware

I have a nuxt app on heroku, and send mysubdom1.mydom.com to the app.
The BaseUrl is defined in my nuxt.config.js as mysubdom1-admin.mydom.com.

It's working fine, but I would like to send mysubdom2.mydom.com to the same app.
And I would like to have the baseUrl, for now defined in my nuxt.config.js, to be mysubdom2-admin.mydom.com.

I tried to use nuxtServerInit, and nuxtClientInit with req.headers.host, but it didn't work.

I think I need to use a server middleware, but I can't find a proper example on how to do what I want.

If someone can point to a very basic exemple on how to do that, it would be of great help.
Thanks !

Comment: Can you share your `nuxt.config.js` file ? It all comes down how you do use your env variables, if they are on build or on runtime.

Comment: I found a solution. Not very elegant, but working.

Comment: You can answer your own question so. This may help people in the future, who knows. Basically to avoid this: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: Hi @kissu, Yes sorry I was about to do it in the comment, but now it's done properly.

Comment: @kissu, just checked your link xD Good one.

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

For any one looking into this, here is the solution I found.

```
env: {
    baseUrl: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://web-admin.exemple.eu' : (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ? 'https://dev-admin.exemple.eu' : (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging' ? 'https://staging-admin.exemple.eu' : (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'motion' ? 'https://motion-admin.exemple.eu' :  'https://web-admin.exemple.eu'))))
  },
```

Comment: Looking back at how simple this is, I can't believe I lost 2 days looking at proxies and middleware....

Comment: I guess you could also make a `switch` or `if/else` condition to avoid nested ternary ! :D

Comment: @kissu can you make a switch or if else in the nuxt.config.js ? I tried but I didn't find the right way to do it. Can you show me how you would do a switch ?

Answer (score 1):

This one should work IMO:

```js
let myVariable = null
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'production':
    myVariable = 'https://web-admin.exemple.eu'
    break
  case 'development':
    myVariable = 'https://dev-admin.exemple.eu'
    break
  default:
    break
}


export default {
  // ..
  // the rest of your nuxt configuration where you can use myVariable
```